# Java WebSockets: OnClose method is not called when closing websocket connection

Tags: java, javascript, jboss, websocket

Here is my `WebSocket` endpoint

```
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.twitter.hbc.core.Client;

@ServerEndpoint("/tweets")
public class TweetStreamServer {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TweetStreamServer.class);

    @OnMessage
    public void tweets(final String message, final Session client) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        LOGGER.debug("registering search term {}", message);
        final TwitterHoseBird twitterHoseBird = new TwitterHoseBird();
        final Client twitterClient = twitterHoseBird.getInstance(message);
        while(!twitterClient.isDone()) {
            client.getAsyncRemote().sendText(twitterHoseBird.getMsgQueue().take());
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(CloseReason reason) {
        System.out.println("Closing connection");
        LOGGER.warn("closing connection {}", reason);
    }
}
```

When I deploy this, I try to hit the endpoint via `JavaScript` code as

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/tweetstream-1.0-SNAPSHOT/tweets');
connection.onmessage = function (e) {
  console.log('Server: ' + e.data);
};
connection.send('fifa');
```

This starts to send tweets from the server. Now when I close the connection from client, I do

```
connection.close();
```

**Problem?**
I want to close connection to twitter once websocket client connection closes. I expect the following code to execute

```
@OnClose
public void onClose(CloseReason reason) {
    System.out.println("Closing connection");
    LOGGER.warn("closing connection {}", reason);
}
```

But on server log, I do not see any such statement

```
/Users/harith/code/installers/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh
=========================================================================
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13.app/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13.app/lib/util.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper /private/var/folders/qs/y62p93xs0bdb9ptk6l2r8vw0002kvk/T/classpath571663656928489966.tmp com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 53801 com.intellij.javaee.oss.jboss.agent.JBoss71Agent

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

[2014-07-12 02:16:06,305] Artifact tweetstream:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
  JBOSS_HOME: /Users/harith/code/installers/wildfly-8.1.0.Final
Detected server admin port: 9990

Detected server http port: 8080
  JAVA: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

[0m14:16:06,048 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
[0m[0m14:16:06,289 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
[0m[0m14:16:06,349 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.1.0.Final "Kenny" starting
[0m[0m14:16:07,165 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
[0m[0m14:16:07,180 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO version 3.2.2.Final
[0m[0m14:16:07,186 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.2.Final
[0m[0m14:16:07,207 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
[0m[33m14:16:07,208 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
[0m[0m14:16:07,211 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
[0m[0m14:16:07,213 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors
[0m[0m14:16:07,219 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
[0m[0m14:16:07,221 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
[0m[0m14:16:07,222 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.21.Beta1
[0m[0m14:16:07,222 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
[0m[0m14:16:07,251 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.15.Final starting
[0m[0m14:16:07,252 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.15.Final starting
[0m[0m14:16:07,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.1.5.Final)
[0m[0m14:16:07,291 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.3.Final
[0m[0m14:16:07,291 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
[0m[0m14:16:07,299 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
[0m[0m14:16:07,346 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
[0m[0m14:16:07,346 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
[0m[0m14:16:07,390 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path /Users/harith/code/installers/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/welcome-content
[0m[0m14:16:07,425 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
[0m[0m14:16:07,498 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
[0m[0m14:16:07,561 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /127.0.0.1:8080
[0m[0m14:16:07,724 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /Users/harith/code/installers/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments
[0m[0m14:16:07,728 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "4f0c2559-5f61-4cf1-b441-c6288b419b80.war" (runtime-name: "4f0c2559-5f61-4cf1-b441-c6288b419b80.war")
[0m[0m14:16:07,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
[0m[0m14:16:07,918 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.4.Final
[0m[0m14:16:08,062 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (MSC service thread 1-11) UT026003: Adding annotated server endpoint class com.self.tweetstream.TweetStreamServer for path /tweets
[0m[0m14:16:08,075 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (MSC service thread 1-11) UT026004: Adding annotated client endpoint class com.self.tweetstream.TweetStreamClient
[0m[0m14:16:08,167 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /4f0c2559-5f61-4cf1-b441-c6288b419b80
[0m[0m14:16:08,203 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "4f0c2559-5f61-4cf1-b441-c6288b419b80.war" (runtime-name : "4f0c2559-5f61-4cf1-b441-c6288b419b80.war")
[0m[0m14:16:08,215 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
[0m[0m14:16:08,215 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
[0m[0m14:16:08,216 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.1.0.Final "Kenny" started in 2554ms - Started 250 of 304 services (91 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
[0mConnected to server
[2014-07-12 02:16:08,683] Artifact tweetstream:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[0m14:16:08,794 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "tweetstream-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "tweetstream-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
[0m[0m14:16:09,408 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment tweetstream-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[0m[0m14:16:09,450 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.0.Final
[0m[0m14:16:09,548 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: tweetstream-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[0m[0m14:16:09,573 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-14) WELD-000900: 2.1.2 (Final)
[0m[0m14:16:09,580 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment tweetstream-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[0m[0m14:16:10,361 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (MSC service thread 1-8) UT026004: Adding annotated client endpoint class com.self.tweetstream.TweetStreamClient
[0m[0m14:16:10,364 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (MSC service thread 1-8) UT026003: Adding annotated server endpoint class com.self.tweetstream.TweetStreamServer for path /tweets
[0m[0m14:16:10,383 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-8) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.6-jbossorg-4 20140501-1134 for context '/tweetstream-1.0-SNAPSHOT'
[0m[0m14:16:11,293 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /tweetstream-1.0-SNAPSHOT
[0m[0m14:16:11,307 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "tweetstream-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "tweetstream-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
[0m[2014-07-12 02:16:11,327] Artifact tweetstream:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2014-07-12 02:16:11,327] Artifact tweetstream:war: Deploy took 2,644 milliseconds
[0m14:16:21,124 INFO  [com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.BasicClient] (default task-2) New connection executed: tweetStream-client, endpoint: /1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length&stall_warnings=true
[0m[0m14:16:21,207 INFO  [com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase] (hosebird-client-io-thread-0) tweetStream-client Establishing a connection
[0m[0m14:16:23,789 INFO  [com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase] (hosebird-client-io-thread-0) tweetStream-client Processing connection data
[0m
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**
I have test as following

```
    @Test
    public void test() throws URISyntaxException, IOException, DeploymentException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("URI: " + getEndpointUrl());
        TweetStreamClient.latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Session session = connectToServer(TweetStreamClient.class, "tweets");
        assertNotNull(session);
        // (todo: harit) assert correct things
//        assertTrue(TweetStreamClient.latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
//        assertEquals("Hello", TweetStreamClient.response);
    }
```

When I run this test, I see following in logs

```
8295 [main] INFO io.undertow.websockets.jsr - UT026004: Adding annotated client endpoint class com.self.tweetstream.TweetStreamClient
14:59:26,981 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS017535: Unregistered web context: /b5b7b561-8b49-4c69-b55f-7859b86da36d
14:59:26,983 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) session id:AMAjTU1TYTCjXBgLOKnMXS6q, search term: Hello World!
14:59:26,985 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Closing session: io.undertow.websockets.jsr.UndertowSession@cd7ecfa
14:59:26,986 WARN  [com.self.tweetstream.TweetStreamServer] (default task-2) closing session: AMAjTU1TYTCjXBgLOKnMXS6q, reason: CloseReason[1001]
```

But when I call `connection.close()` from JavaScript, I do not see such thing

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem and initially thought it was a Wildfly issue, but then noticed that Firefox was triggering @OnClose. When I added an @OnError, Chromium was triggering that.

I found an [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599185/websocket-closing-browser-triggers-onerror-in-chrome-but-onclose-event-in-f) referring to the same behavior.

It also appears that Chromium may have just [fixed this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=51687) as of a month ago.

Comment: but this is really fragile, because if one user closes tab and other 100s of user are still actively listening on the socket, undertow will close all of the connections, isn't it? any way to avoid it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741478/javaee-websocket-closing-browser-tab-closes-all-sessions-irrespective-of-browse

Comment: We have the same issue, onClose() is simply not called... Do you have any solution?