# JavaEE Websocket: closing browser tab closes all sessions irrespective of browser

Tags: java, javascript, session, jakarta-ee, websocket

I have a websocket endpoint as

```
@ServerEndpoint("/tweets")
public class TweetStreamServer {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TweetStreamServer.class);

    @OnMessage
    public void tweets(final String message, final Session session) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("session id:" + session.getId() + ", search term: " + message);
        final Client twitterClient = TwitterHoseBird.getInstance(message);
        while (!session.getOpenSessions().isEmpty()) {
            for (final Session s : session.getOpenSessions()) {
                if (twitterClient.isDone()) {
                    System.out.println("Twitter Client Done, waiting ...");
                }
                s.getBasicRemote().sendText(TwitterHoseBird.getMsgQueue().take());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I deploy this on `WildFly 8.1.0 Final`. Then I open multiple tabs on `Chrome`, `Safari` and run the following

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/tweetstream-1.0-SNAPSHOT/tweets');
connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send('germany');
};
connection.onerror = function (error) {
  console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
};
connection.onmessage = function (e) {
  console.log('Server: ' + e.data);
};
connection.onclose = function (e) {
  console.log('closing session');
};
```

Then all the tabs start receiving data from server.

- Then when I do `connection.close();` on one of the tabs, only that connection breaks while all the other tabs are still receiving the data
- But if I close one of the tabs (in any browser), all the sessions that were open in all the other tabs close session with `closing session` message

**Question**
- Is it not a valid use case that if user closes a tab in one browser, all the other tabs should still receive the data?
- Do you see any bug/issue with what I am doing?
- How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
s.getBasicRemote().sendText(TwitterHoseBird.getMsgQueue().take());
```

change it to

```
s.getAsyncRemote().sendText(TwitterHoseBird.getMsgQueue().take());
```

and everything else would just workout fine